# Running Python script on HTML page

Tags: javascript, python, html

I would like to basically call a Python script from HTML, after the script is called and it has finished running, I would like to execute a JavaScript file(which I know how to do.)

Now my question is: Can I do this with just pure HTML and JavaScript or do I need to get a library for Python? If I don't need a library, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: ...Just reference the Python file in the HTML?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Like I do with Javascript? That had crossed my mind but how would I execute it on a button press though? And in that way would I even be able to wait until the script is finished running?

Comment: What **exactly** are you trying to do? You can point to the Python file directly from a button's link, or alternatively, run it automatically with `cronjobs`. And what happens when the script finishes running? You could simply direct users to the Python page, and then show a 'Loading, please wait' message from the script itself, and then when it's finished running update the HTML and include the JavaScript file.

Comment: I have a python script that returns a JSON file. What I'm trying to accomplish is: Once a user presses the button, the python script runs server sided. It returns the most recent json file to the server. Then I execute a javascript file that reads the json file and acts accordingly. @ObsidianAge

Comment: so, you're looking at doing some [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX) I would guess

Comment: You may want to use the flask library for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use Two Python libraries.

1. Django
2. Flask

I recommend Django. Django is easy and fast to make.

the Flask is more complex but you can make more detail functions.

Comment: I would say the opposite. Flask is a much lighter framework.

Comment: I'm sorry. My answer may make you confused. I mean that when you make same website, If you use Django, you can make it more easier, faster and simpler  because of many various library from Django. But If you use Flask, It is more complex to make the same website. (I mean you shoud invest more time to make it and you feel complex) I know Flask is a much lighter and simple. But In the my answer, 'complex' is different from your word.

Comment: May I suggest then, "Flask is lighter, so quicker to learn but not as powerful. I recommend Django, as it's much easier to use once you've learned it."? Also I would mention that (I imagine) extending Flask will be easier than extending Django. I assume this is what you meant by "you can make more detail functions".

Comment: Good summary, That is what i want to talk.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I do this with just pure HTML and javascript?

You might want to execute python on the browser, then look at something like this http://www.skulpt.org/, but the most common use case is that no, you need to execute javascript on the browser client-side and python on server-side

So no, you need something that executes python in a web server (apache/nginx) context, like

- gunicorn (standalone/wsgi)
- uwsgi (standalone/wsgi)
- mod_python (apache module)

Then you would execute like this for example

```
browser ---http---> server(nginx) ---wsgi---> python_server(uwsgi)+library(Django)
      <-------------/            <------------/
```

Comment: However all I want to do is: Tell the server to execute the python script server sided. Thats all, because the python script will return a json file wich is what i want in the 1st place. Isnt there a simple solution to all of this considering all I want is to make the python script run, no saving the response, no sending data to it, just making it execute?